# Angular Inheritance Inject Different Instances

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, singleton

I have 2 component which same as each other. The only diference is their names and some html headers. Because of that I want to use inheritance.

I have created an abstract service:

```
export abstract class AbstractFilmListService {

  protected readonly API = WebUtils.RESOURCE_HOST_API + 'film/';


  constructor(protected client: HttpClient) {
  }

  deleteFilm(filmId: number) {
    return this.client.delete(this.API + filmId);
  }

  fetchFilms(): Observable<Film[]> {
    return this.client.get(this.API) as Observable<Film[]>;
  }
}
```

Sublass 1:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilmListService extends AbstractFilmListService {
  constructor(protected client: HttpClient) {
    super(client);
  }
}
```

SubClass 2:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SeriesListService extends AbstractFilmListService{

  protected readonly API: string;

  constructor(client: HttpClient) {
    super(client);
    this.API = WebUtils.SERIES_API;
  }
}
```

So far everything is all right. But I want to do same things with components:

FilmListComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-film-list',
  templateUrl: './film-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./film-list.component.css']
})
export class FilmListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(protected client: HttpClient,
              protected router: Router,
              protected snackService: SnackService,
              protected filmListService: FilmListService // <- Problem is here !
              ) {
  }
//....

}
```

SeriesListComponent:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-series-list',
  templateUrl: './series-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./series-list.component.css']
})
export class SeriesListComponent extends FilmListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(protected client: HttpClient,
              protected router: Router,
              protected snackService: SnackService,
              protected filmListService: FilmListService // <- Problem is here!
  ) {
    super(client, router, snackService, filmListService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to `FilmListComponent` declare  `AbstractFilmListService` instead of `FilmListService` and when it start to inject service it should injects `FilmListService`.

Same way `SeriesListComponent` should declare  `AbstractFilmListService` instead of `FilmListService` and when it start to inject service it should injects `SeriesListService`.

I mean something like that:

```
export class FilmListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
             // ...
              protected filmListService: AbstractFilmListService
              ) {
          this.filmListService = new FilmListService(); // Angular should do  something like this...
  }
//....

}
```

Same thing for SeriesListComponent:

```
export class SeriesListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
             // ...
              protected filmListService: AbstractFilmListService
              ) {
          this.filmListService = new SeriesListService(); // Angular should do  something like this...
  }
//....

}
```

I know Angular doesn't create new Services for each Component it uses Singleton Design Pattern for Dependency Injection. In order to make clear myself I have written

```
"new SeriesListService(), new FilmListService()"
```

**How do I inject different instances for different components even if their types declared same in constuructor?**

---

**Update**

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    ActorComponent,
    FilmComponent,
    SeriesComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    SafeUrlPipe,
    FilmListComponent,
    HeroComponent,
    CoverComponent,
    SeasonComponent,
    ChapterComponent,
    SeriesListComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RoutingModule,
    TokenModule,
    MaterialModule,
    NgbTimepickerModule,
    HttpInterceptorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: It depends on where you are providing your services. You can provide one of them like so: `providers: [ { provide: AbstractFilmListService, useClass: SeriesListService } ]`, but if they are provided in the same module, then the second provided service will override the first. It seems like you want to use `AbstractFilmListService` as an injection token. Could I see the module where you've provided your services?

Comment: Of course I am adding my module.

Answer (score 1):

If its not going to be a singleton service it doesn't make that much sense to use `providedIn` in my opinion.

But to answer your question, if you want different instances of this service you should provide the service in the `@Component` annotation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-series-list',
  templateUrl: './series-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./series-list.component.css'],
  providers: [AbstractFilmListService] // <-- will create a new instance for this component
})
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be: ```providers: [ { provide: AbstractFilmListService, useClass: SeriesListService } ]```, since just providing AbstractFilmListService will create an instance of the abstract class (not that abstract classes can be instantiated), but he wants a specific derived class to be injected, although I might be wrong.

Comment: @Wingnod ah thanks, I was a bit lazy on reading i must admit :-) Just wanted to give the main idea on hierarchical DI

Comment: No problem! Other than that bit, I also think this is the best solution to his problem :)